# Type 'Observable<true | Promise<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have Guard with `canActivate` method:

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      return this.fireAuth.authState.pipe(
        take(1),
        map(authState => !!authState),
        map(auth => !auth ? this.router.navigate(['/']) : true)
      )
  }
```

This is work, but I have typescript error in console:

> ERROR in auth.guard.ts(20,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable | Promise'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md

Comment: @Jota.Toledo wow, never knew about built in guards in fire auth

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `map()`. You don't want to change the emitted value. You just want to produce a side effect.

```
take(1),
map(authState => !!authState),
tap(auth => {
  if (!auth) {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
});
```

Or, if it makes it simpler to understand to you:

```
take(1),
map(authState => {
  if (authState) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Or better, return a UrlTree instead of navigating yourself when the router must navigate elsewhere:

```
take(1),
map(authState => !!authState || this.router.parseUrl('/'))
```

Comment: But I changed it from `tap` to `map` because you told me in this question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448349/guard-always-return-true` :D

Comment: No, I never told you that. Re-read my answer. I explained what map() does and what tap() does. You were expecting tap() to change the emitted value, and I explaiend that it wasn't. And I explained that you were emitting the same value in both cases from map(), whereas one should have emitted the inverse of the other.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand, how should I change my code. If I change it to `tap` - then it's just didn't work, but when I left it how it is - it's work, but I have typescript errors.

Comment: I posted two ways of implementing it. You need to think about two different things. 1. when should the guard authorize the navigation? The returned observable must emit true if it's authorized, and false or a UrlTree otherwise 2. If it doesn't authorise the navigation, should it navigate elsewhere? If it should, then it should navigate and return false, or return a UrlTree to where it should navigate.